# error visualStudio y sql conexión

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

> No se encontraron recursos adecuados para la referencia cultural
> especificada o para la referencia cultural neutra. Compruebe si
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Providers.SqlServer.SqlViewSupport.xml"
> se ha incrustado o vinculado  correctamente en el ensamblado
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Providers.SqlServer" durante el tiempo de
> compilación o que todos los ensamblados satélite requeridos pueden
> cargarse y están completamente firmados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta la encontré aquí, me funcionó ya que tenía el mismo problema.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Could-not-find-any-resources-appropriate/1505966#T-N1506125

Descargas el archivo zip y lo copias reemplazando los actuales en la siguiente ruta:
(Para mi es la versión professional)

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE

Saludos

Comment: hola, dure horas intentando conocer el por que del error y como darle solución muchas gracias 